# Xamarin set ItemSources to a List in a different dll

Tags: listview, xamarin, itemsource

I have a project for Xamarin. I have my logic in a GameBrain.dll (a normal C# dll I share with a WPF project) and in there I have a `public static List<Puzzle> Puzzles`

Then I have the Xamarin forms project where I have my view that looks like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:GameBrainControl;assembly=GameBrain"
         x:Class="GB.AutoPuzzlesPage">

    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Static local:Game}">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</ContentPage>
```

and I get `Syntax for x:Static is [Member=][prefix:]typeName.staticMemberName` What's the proper syntax to reference my List ???

Comment: You have to add the source  try with this, ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static  local:Game}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming:

- `local` is the key for the namespace (and assembly),
- `Game` is the static class,
- `Puzzles` is the `static List`:

This gives the syntax:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Static local:Game.Puzzles}">
...
```

Comment: how can I link to it .. if is not static ?